# Host not found in Ansible inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to do some testing against a specific host with Ansible 2.5 but ansible can't figure out my inventory. I've either done something wrong or there's a bug. I've done this in the past but maybe something changed in 2.5

I have an inventory file specified like this:

```
localhost   ansible_connection=local
testhost   ansible_ssh_host=1.2.3.4
```

I have a playbook that runs totally fine if i just run it with `ansible playbook.yml`. It starts like this:

```
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: sudo
  gather_facts: yes
```

If I run `ansible-inventory --list` I see both of my hosts listed as "ungrouped"

However, if I try to run my playbook against the remote host using `ansible -l testhost playbook.yml` it errors with the following:

```
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: playbook.yml

ERROR! Specified hosts and/or --limit does not match any hosts
```

I can't figure out how to actually make Ansible run against my remote host.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your playbook specifies only `localhost`, limiting to `testhost` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Your playbook specifies:

```
hosts: localhost
```

It will not run on `testfile` regardless of the arguments you supply. `--limit` does not replace the `hosts` declaration.

---

As your hosts are ungrouped, you need to change this to:

```
hosts: all
```

Then you can use limit option to filter the hosts from the given target group.

---

You are also using wrong command to run an Ansible playbook, it should be `ansible-playbook` not `ansible` (and although the effect is the same, the latter does not fail with an error in such case).

Comment: even if the inventory file is the system default (/etc/ansible/hosts)??? I don't remember having to do this in the past

Answer (score 0):

use simple method wherever you have to connect on local system? just specify `connection : local` to hosts block

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection : local
  become: yes
  become_user: root
```